# Creating threads in Rxjava

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, rx-java2

I am passing two arguments in `just()` operator. Snippet of my code is :

```
Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.just(1,2);
observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                        .subscribe(
                                new Observer<Integer>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete() {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onNext(Integer e) {
                                        System.out.println(e);
                                        //request web service

                                });
```

What I observed is it is not making separate thread for each emitted item. Items appearing as `just` arguments are running sequentially. How to create separate thread for each emitted item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flatMap and inside the flatMap create the new observable and use the subscribeOn

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Observable.just(1, 2)
            .flatMap(item -> Observable.just(item)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("Thread:" + Thread.currentThread())))
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

You can see more examples about async observable here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/scheduler/ObservableAsynchronous.java

Comment: Thanks @paul. It worked. But why my previous method didn't work?

Comment: Because since you dont create a new observable with observable.subscribeOn both items emitted in that observable are running in the same thread